# How did the cabin crew know that I didn't get my preferred meal in a previous flight?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, loyalty-programs, cabin-crew

In a recent flight, I ordered fish, but it was not available, the crew apologized and offered me another meal.

Anyway, I flew after that with the same airline, and when they started serving  meals, a crew member came to me, greeted me by name and apologized again on behalf of the airline for not being able to serve me fish in my previous flight!

They asked me if I would like to try the fish in this flight, I said yes and I got it.

How did they know that?

Comment: Which airline we talking about here?

Comment: Every airline has their own passenger records, separate and in addition to those required for ticketing.

Comment: Not you of course, but the usual way they would know is because the passenger has been shouting to everyone from the airline's board of directors on down about how he's a super-ultra-premium-Unobtanium member of the frequent flyer program and he didn't get his preferred meal choice last flight. The gate agent bought some fish and chips from the airport pub and left them in the galley in the hope of shutting you up.

Comment: Be sure to leave a kind thankyou note with the airline about this.  Most do actually read comments/complaints.

Comment: Amadeus has a post-flight PNR update - they can take the cabin crew comments on the manifest, and update the booking (and customer FF record after that) - depends on the airline whether they use this or not (and the cabin crew bothering to do it), but the facility is there in this GDS. The crew certainly notify if there are any meal-outages, that's for sure - that's just a general complaint to catering though. The longer-haul the flight the more likely they are to do it. I'd imagine a quality airline like SQ would be more likely to track this stuff than other airlines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on the flight routing, air crews do have the ability to communicate with the airline offices during the flight.

Most likely in this case, the fact that a special meal cart was improperly stocked was relayed to the operations office, either during flight or upon landing.  A caring staff member who received that communique probably made a note in your booking record.  And a thoughtful flight attendant who saw the note came to express an apology.

Passenger manifests are constantly updated right up until the door closes. And they contain quite a few tidbits about the passengers for the flight attendants reference. So it is quite easy for your issue to have been noted before the flight left.

Comment: Sure, but given the question asker is a flight attendant himself he clearly knew that - obviously he's looking for a more existential answer!

Comment: @Doc - How am I supposed to know the OP's profession?  I have neither the time nor the motivation to memorize everyone's past posts or comments (and now looking at the profile, the OP has been through several name changes to boot).  Perhaps you should be probing the OP as to why they are asking a question they should already know the answer for.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little known fact that most airline flight attendants are actually psychically linked, in a way not dissimilar to that shown by the "Borg" in the television show "Star Trek" (or is that Star Wars? I always get those two confused. Whichever one it was that had Picard in it, and not the one with James Earl Jones).

Using a "hive mind" allows these flight attendants to share what experiences their passengers have had on previous flights, and attempt to overcome poor experiences - such as your lack of fish - on future flights.

Clearly the flight attendant on the second flight "remembered" you - using this shared consciousness with the flight attendant from the first flight - and thus was able to overcome the shortage of fish issue.

It's also possible (although realistically far less likely) that they just keep records and notes from one flight to the next on some form of a computer system, based on your name or frequent flyer information or something. Such a computer system may seem like science fiction, but I'm reliably information by Wired magazine that computers can do things like that now!

Comment: @Doc could you please edit your answer to remove the sarcastic part?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException there would be little left.